# How to print a C# Windows form as a word doc would be printed?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

How to print a Windows form as a word doc would be printed?

I do have a windows form, the content of which, including labels and textbox values, i want to print. I did have the thought of using reports, but it would be very hard to create it, so i'm asking for a simple way of doing it (the printing). So this question popped out. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

in visual studio 2008 in c# under Visual basic Powerpacks there is a PrintForm object you can add, the tool tip states "allows you to easily print a window form as a simple report."

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/printawinformsusercontrol.aspx) that should walk you through what you want.